# show two values in select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to display two values inside the select-box, I tried the following way but the brackets are shown:

```
<%= select_tag :sucursal, options_for_select(@sucursales.map{|e|[[e.IdEmpresa, e.Sucursal], e.IdEmpresa]}) %>
```

How I can display both values in the select-box without displaying the brackets?

Comment: What is the desired output? And please format your code.

Comment: Display two values in the selectbox that are e.IdEmpresa, e.Sucursal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe interpolation?

```
<%= select_tag :sucursal, options_for_select(@sucursales.map{|e| ["#{e.IdEmpresa} - #{e.Sucursal}", e.IdEmpresa]}) %>
```

Why are you using those weird column names? Legacy system?